# Printing content in for loop causing PHP to crash possibly due to Apache?

Tags: php, apache, foreach

I have a foreach loop that iterates through comments as such:

```
<?php 
    $comments = get_comments(array("status"=>"approve"));
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) { ?>
    <div class="comment">
        <h2><? echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, "subject", $single = true ); ?></h2>
        <p class="message"><?=$comment->comment_content;?></p>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

When I run it on a live server, I get the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\UniServer\www\apps\app_name\wp-content\themes\sube\page-feedback.php on line 53`

This doesn't happen when I run the site locally.. so I'm thinking its a server configuration error.

Also, when I change the code so that it echo's the content, it works fine. For example:

```
<?php 
    $comments = get_comments(array("status"=>"approve"));
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    echo '<div class="comment">
        <h2>'; get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, "subject", $single = true ); echo'</h2>
        <p class="message">'.$comment->comment_content.'</p>
    </div>';
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your live server may not have the `asp_tags` php.ini directive set. According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), this is what enables the variable-value printing shorthand. You will also want to make sure `short_open_tag` is enabled too.

Comment: Ah it was the short_open_tag boolean set to false. I set it to true in the .htaccess file and all is now working. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

> This doesn't happen when I run the site locally.. so I'm thinking its a server configuration error.

Yes, this is because of a feature called [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). That feature must be enabled to allow for the short form syntax style you are using, such as `<?=` (which is short for `<?php echo`), etc.

As you can read in the manual, the short form will cause a conflict if you also intend to use `<?xml ?>` tags, verbatim, in your PHP files.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `echo` in front of `get_comment_meta()`